# Split string issues in following query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following query which inserts data into two columns in a table. If we notice, it actually creates only two rows instead of three rows, because I have specified only '2' in `'CONNECT BY'` clause. It clearly omits third values because of this. is there a way to change this behavior without changing its position. I am not able to specify `CONNECT BY` again in same query.AS  My values are dynamic not able to change its position.

**Expected output**

```
Name Country
a     xy
c     yx
null  xc
```

**Query tried**

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_test_customer (
                NAME,
                COUNTRY
                
            )
                    SELECT
                    TRIM(regexp_substr('a,c', '[^,]+', 1, level)) str,
                     TRIM(regexp_substr('xy,yx,xc', '[^,]+', 1, level)) stri
                FROM
                    dual
                CONNECT BY 
                    instr('a,c', ',', 1, level - 1) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two `connect by` clauses - just fix the one you have, so that it takes larger of two values:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    TRIM(regexp_substr('a,c', '[^,]+', 1, level)) str,
  3    TRIM(regexp_substr('xy,yx,xc', '[^,]+', 1, level)) stri
  4  FROM dual
  5  CONNECT BY level <= greatest (regexp_count('a,c', ','),
  6                                regexp_count('xy,yx,xc', ',')
  7                               ) + 1;

STR          STRI
------------ --------------------------------
a            xy
c            yx
             xc

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried another variant based on your solution, it also works hope I have done correct way        `SELECT
     regexp_substr('Name:a,Name:c', '(Name:)?(.*?)(,Name:|$)', 1, level, NULL, 2),
       TRIM(regexp_substr('xy,yx,xc', '[^,]+', 1, level)) stri
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY level <= greatest (regexp_count('Name:a,Name:c', 'Name:'),
                                      regexp_count('xy,yx,xc', ',')
                                     ) + 1;`